# How to liquify butter -- and keep it liquid?

Tags: butter

Is there a way to liquify butter and keep it in a liquid form at room temperature (at minimum) or in a refrigerator (preferably)? I can't seem to find any solution on the web. Everything seems to point to making clarified butter, which is not what I want (plus, the `ghee` I've seen is solid at room temperature).

Is there anything I can do / add to the butter to keep it liquid?

Comment: I will leave a full answer to those around here who are better at chemistry, because they may know some trick. But pure butter, I see no way. You are basically asking to change the melting-point of the various bits butter is made up of, which most likely won't happen; that's why people keep telling you to go for clarified butter. There MAY be a way to force the melted butter into an emulsion with something liquid, but that's more "adding things" than you possibly want.

Comment: I'm open to adding things -- like water. I just discovered Beurre Monte and am currently testing it out. I'll leave it in room temperature overnight, then refrigerate the next day to observe its properties.

Comment: What is this for? Given that there are so many liquid fats to choose from, why use a solid one? If it has to be butter, why does it have to stay permanently liquid? Why in a refrigerator and not in a heated box? What are your requirements for the resulting liquid (viscosity, remaining milk solids, etc.) In general, what you want exactly as stated is impossible. There can be workarounds, but if we have to suggest some, we have to know which properties the result can lose and which are essential.

Comment: What you are asking is no different than asking, "How do i keep water liquid in my freezer?" The fats in the butter will solidify at room temperature. There's no way around it. If you have a specific reason for needing liquid room temperature butter, explain the reason and we may be able to provide a reasonable substitute.

Comment: I'm making hot sauce, which includes butter. I don't want the sauce solidifying. I want it always ready for use. Would like to be able to keep in refrigerated without having to go through the hassle of warming it up to liquefy.

Comment: Please edit clarifications into your question. Not everyone reads all comments, and they shouldn't have to.

Comment: Your sauce won't solidify because there are other ingredients mixed on it (I suppose). Unless there's a huge proportion of butter in it. So you don't need liquid butter.

Comment: Just wondering if you ever found an answer/solution to this? By the way you can get a product from Corman called "Liquid clarified butter". I has a fat ratio of 99,9 % and stays liquid in the fridge but is made from 100% milk fats. They also do a roasted butter one that's 98% fat. https://www.corman-pro-artisan.com/en/products/30-liquid-clarified-butter-999-fat Sadly I can't get it in the UK unless I order a pallet of it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could blend it with an oil that does not itself solidify in the refrigerator, but that's no longer butter, it's possibly "butter flavored oil" - don't use olive or coconut as they solidify in the fridge (or moderate room temperature for the coconut.)

Comment: Just blend? No other steps?

Answer (score 3):

4th & Heart makes a ghee oil that remains liquid at room temperature by blending 60 percent ghee & 40 percent grape seed oil. It's pourable. Don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any way to keep butter in a liquid state, but here are two suggestions to give you the flavor without having to worry about the butter re-solidifying:

1. A natural butter flavoring or extract.
2. Margarine spray such as I Can't Believe It's Not Butter or Parkay spray. They can be found in the dairy aisle with the regular margarines. This should give you a buttery flavor and they are already in a liquid state. (These are *not* the ones in a spray can that would be used as a non-stick spray.)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.... clarified butter is close to a liquid at room temp; soft at least, and you can keep it on your counter for a couple months without it going bad. Most hot sauces, Tabasco and such, can be kept at room temp. If you're making a hot sauce and not adding ingredients that go bad at room temp, why not just make your hot sauce, add a little olive oil or whatever to keep it liquid and keep it out of the fridge?

Answer (score 0):

It it’s for cooking ie. a butter injection into a chicken or turkey, you will need to add chicken broth (heated) then melt the desired amount of butter, add some garlic, some herbs….voila. It will stay liquid for days in the fridge. I will then smoke my turkey for hours then use what’s left for a baste hours after it’s been in the fridge.